# How to pass image as parameter in React navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

this is how i'm passing my data through navigation

```
<FlatList
        horizontal={false}
        numColumns={3}
        data={data}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (

            <TouchableOpacity
       onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Image",item)}
          >
                 <View style={{flex:1}}>
              <Image
                source={{ uri: item.photo }}
                style={{ width: 140, height: 140 }}
             />
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
      />
```

this is how i'm retrieving text input

```
export default function Image({navigation,route}) {
        const { photo, name } = route.params;
    return (
        <View>
           <Text> {JSON.stringify(name)}</Text>
         </View>
    )
}
```

text is actually passing perfectly and outputting
but when i try to retrieve image url it gives error
*undefined is not an object (evaluating 'route.params')*
**for this code**

```
export default function Image({navigation,route}) {
    
    
    const { photo, name } = route.params;


    return (
        <View>
            <Text> {JSON.stringify(name)}</Text>
       
            <Image
      
        source={{uri:JSON.stringify(photo)}}
      />
       
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: What is the error and how are you using `photo` that generates an error for it but not for `name`? What does `name` resolve to?

Comment: i updated the code @j1mbl3s please check now

Comment: can you show your data array?